# Maven property by multiple lines

Tags: java, maven, properties, resources

During the maven build i need to replace one property by multiple lines : here is the example

file1.xml

```
  <default>true</default>   
  <type>sybase</type>   
  <driver>com.sybase.jdbc6.jdbc.SybConnectionPoolDataSource</driver>   
  <url>jdbc:sybase:Tds:server:1000/APP?charset=iso_1</url>    
  ${property1}
```

I want to replace the property1 by the following test

```
  <login>admin</login>   
  <password>pass</password>   
  <initial>1</initial>   
  <maximal>5</maximal>   
  <delay>-1</delay>   
  <trace>false</trace>
```

How should I do it ? I can not put in the po.xml all those line inside one property.

Comment: This is not the purpose of Maven, so you are doing the right thing if you use an external tool. I suggest to just use a *bash* or *powershell* script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use CDATA section:

```xml
<properties>

        <property1>
            <![CDATA[
                  <login>admin</login>
                  <password>pass</password>
                  <initial>1</initial>
                  <maximal>5</maximal>
                  <delay>-1</delay>
                  <trace>false</trace>
            ]]>
        </property1>

</properties>
```